# How to use my custom COM dll with Auto HotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I am currently writing an app and I want to give AHK access to it.

The library is written in VB.NET and contains only one class and 1 method. A snippet is below.

```
Public Class MYAppConnect

‘This is the method I want to call
Public Sub FindIt(ByVal aFN As String)
    ‘here is where the work is done
End sub

End Class
```

This library is registered and working fine. For example I can use the library from another project or from a VBA office program like access or word.  This means it is registering correctly in the registry.

I know nothing about AHK so how can I use my library from AHK?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Function in AutoHotkey that you are looking for is: [DLLCall](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/DllCall.htm)

Here's some Tutorial's on the usage of DllCall:

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/88313-my-dllcall-tutorial-for-beginnersmessagebox/
http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?t=406